# Compile a .tex file from a hard link in the original directory

Tags: compiling, ubuntu, unix

I'm using LaTeX on Ubuntu 20.04 with the Tex Live distribution.

Recently, I tried to create hard links to some LaTeX files and put them in a specific folder of my Linux computer, using the Unix ln command.

I can normally read and modify a .tex file by opening the associated link but on the compilation the output files are saved in the links folder, not in the original directory.

Is there any way to solve this issue ?

Comment: isn't that what you would expect? Especially with hard links, but also soft, the link acts just like a regular file in most contexts so tex doesn't really know it's a link at all, if you run tex on the link it will treat it as a file and write the output in that directory (as will most other programs)

Comment: I assume this a normal behavior from a hard link, but I can't even open the target file using a soft link (ln -s command). So how should it be done ?

Comment: why are you using links??? As I say By design tex (and almost all other programs) will treat the link (whether hard or soft) as a file. Tex simply doesn't know it is a link, just as it doesn't know if the directory is on a filesystem on your machine or mounted over the network, these filesystem details are abstracted away by design.

Comment: note it is not just the output location. The input directory will be your link directory: if your file has `\input{chapter1/file.tex}` then your _link_ directory will need a chapter1 directory containing a file.tex, this might be different than the chapter1/file.tex in your target directory, so the pdf you get from running tex  on the link or its target may be completely different